# gdb not giving the complete description of the error

Tags: linux, gdb, g++

I have just shifted to ubuntu and newly using gdb and g++ . Please forgive me if my question is silly .

This is from Richard Stevens Advanced Linux Programming . Three files were created in the folder names reciprocal 
`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "reciprocal.hpp"
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;
  i = atoi (argv[1]);
  printf ("The reciprocal of %d is %g\n", i, reciprocal (i));
  return 0;
}
```

`reciprocal.cpp`:

```
#include <cassert>
#include "reciprocal.hpp"
double reciprocal (int i) {
  // I should be non-zero.
  assert (i != 0);
  return 1.0/i;
}
```

`reciprocal.hpp`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern double reciprocal (int i);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

After compiling , I ran the command `(gdb) reciprocal` and the `(gdb) run` . I was expecting something as in the book

```
Starting program: reciprocal
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strtol_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=0x0, base=10, group=0)
at strtol.c:287
287 strtol.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

But I got :

```
Starting program: /home/trafalgar/Desktop/reciprocal/reciprocal
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000

Program received signal SIGSEGV , Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a56ad4 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

What might be happening different . Is this a version problem or anything else ?

Here is the Makefile

```
reciprocal: main.o reciprocal.o
           g++ $(CFLAGS) -o reciprocal main.o reciprocal.o
main.o: main.c reciprocal.hpp
           gcc $(CFLAGS) -c main.c
reciprocal.o: reciprocal.cpp reciprocal.hpp
           g++ $(CFLAGS) -c reciprocal.cpp
clean:
      rm -f *.o reciprocal
```

Comment: I thought setting on the verbosity will help but still it is giving the same output as before

Comment: The debugger is working (on binaries with debug info). Your code is not working.

Comment: Cleanup with `rm -v *.o recpirocal`. Recompile again all the source codes. Show us your compilation commands. Start the debugger again.

Answer (score 3):

How did you compile the program?

`use g++ -g programname.c`

also, when you do 

`gdb reciprocal`

note if there is a message like

`loaded symbols from ...`

or

`couldnot find symbols`

if you get output similar to 2nd code statement, then the problem is that you did not use -g symbol.

Comment: I used the -g symbol but still its the same , any other suggestions

Comment: could you please paste the exact output when you write gdb reciprocal starting from the point where you execute the program?

Comment: symbols are not getting generated, hence they are not loaded. We will need your compilation statement.

Comment: I used a Makefile , and then `make CFLAGS=-g`

Comment: Please have a look at the make file

Comment: add this line to Makefile on the top CFLAGS=-g I am able to get following output:

Comment: shehbaz@debian:~/stackoverflow$ gdb reciprocal 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/shehbaz/stackoverflow/reciprocal...done.

Comment: @shehbaz Yes till this part its the same but when i run the `run` command then it is showing no information

Answer (score 2):

You should compile with all warnings and debug info, i.e.

```
 gcc -Wall -g -c main.c
 g++ -Wall -g -c reciprocal.cpp
```

then link with

```
 g++ -g main.o reciprocal.o -o reciprocal
```

So add

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -g
```

in your `Makefile`. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108).

Then run the debugger with

```
 gdb reciprocal
```

then set a program argument with `set args 12` command to `(gdb)` prompt
at last start the debugged program with `run` when having the `(gdb)` prompt

Of course, if you don't have any program arguments, `argc` is 1 and `argv[1]` is `NULL`, which you should not pass to [atoi(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html).

The debugger works quite well. **The bug is in your code.** You should handle *correctly* the case when `argc` is 1 and `argv[1]` is `NULL`.

If you encounter a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) inside a C library function, use the `bt` or `backtrace` gdb command to understand how you get there.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working properly, with expected output.

Compare:

```
1. Starting program: reciprocal
2. Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
3. __strtol_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=0x0, base=10, group=0)
4. at strtol.c:287
5. 287 strtol.c: No such file or directory.

A. Starting program: /home/trafalgar/Desktop/reciprocal/reciprocal
B. warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
C. Program received signal SIGSEGV , Segmentation fault.
D. 0x00007ffff7a56ad4 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Lines 1-5 are your expected output (from Mr Stevens' text), lines A-D are your actual output.

Lines 1 & A, are essentially identical, they both specify the filename of the executable, (1) is relative pathed, (A) has full path.  No worries.

Line B... this is NORMAL, this is gdb telling you that you don't have the debugging information installed for your library functions (NOT YOUR CODE, the dynamically linked libraries on your system).

Line C... Same as (2), easy enough.

Line D... Well, since we don't have debug info for the library functions, it can only point out where the error was as best it can:  libc.so.6  (standard library functions, of which strtol is one such)

Essentially, line D is similar to lines 3-5.   Without the debug information installed/available, you're not going to get much more information than this.

But everything is working as expected.  You're fine.

For help on how to install debug symbols, see here: [how-to-use-debug-libraries-on-ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344654/how-to-use-debug-libraries-on-ubuntu)

Fear not!  You're doing great.  (Technically, the error is on line 6 of your main.cpp, since argv[1] is pretty much undefined because you didn't supply an argument, perhaps confusing since atoi() is often replaced with strtol() behind the scenes.)

Try:

```
gdb --args ./reciprocal 15
```

or similar to test with arguments.